# Como fazer o refresh a uma formulário no access?

Tags: formulário, microsoft-access

Estou tentando fazer um `refresh` a um formulário, evitando **fechá-lo** a **abri-lo**, e pensei nesta função. Contudo, sem sucesso. Como posso fazer esse procedimento?

```
Public Fuction (f As a String)    
    Forms(f).Recalc    
    Forms(f).Refresh    
    Forms(f).Repaint    
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Crie um Macro, que o mesmo já tem essa funcionalidade de Atualizar e referencia tal macro para um botão.

Foi criado como exemplo, um macro com o nome de `Macro1`, e o seu comando `Atualizar`.

Guia: ***Criar e botão Macro***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após essa criação do macro, faça o seguinte coloque um `button` na tela do seu formulário, e na guia *Evento* no evento `Ao clicar` escolha o `Macro1`. Pronto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema.

Assim funcionou:

```
Forms!NomeForm.Form.RecordSource = Forms!NomeForm.Form.RecordSource
```